# Android adb command to get device driver in device?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, kernel-module, android-kernel

In android device, I am searching command or way to check all kernel modules/drivers in current device.
so, can we get all kernel module list from command line ?

Command to list all kernel module/driver for static + run time modules.
like lsmod

Comment: Not clear, do you want to have the list of devices that have drivers at run-time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can check it through "adb shell ls sys/module/".
it will list almost every module inside device static and dynamic.

```
adb shell ls sys/module/
```